# If date selected in first field, second field date should be more than first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two date fields in HTML form. If I Select a date in first field, the second field should show date greater than the first field in date picker.
Here are my Date Picker code:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.dt', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

And here is my form having two fields:

```
<td width="212">
    <input type="date" class="dt" name="s_invoice_date_draft1" 
        value="<?php echo @$_REQUEST['s_invoice_date_draft1']; ?>">
    To 
    <input type="date" class="dt" name="s_invoice_date_draft2" 
        value="<?php echo @$_REQUEST['s_invoice_date_draft2']; ?>">
</td>
```

Need solution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two inputs `inp_begintime` and `inp_endtime`, then just initialize the date picker in this way, here when you will change the date of `inp_begintime` it will set `minDate` for `inp_endtime` and if you set date in `inp_endtime` it will set `maxDate` for `inp_begintime`.

```
$("#inp_begintime").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#inp_endtime").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});

$("#inp_endtime").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#inp_begintime").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ckpbqwjk/)

Comment: Would be more helpful if you show how to connect with the html form.

Comment: @user3445158 just create two input fields and give them id `inp_begintime` and `inp_endtime`

Comment: please share if any external source being used

Comment: Ok. Working now. Thanks.